# Need to get string from NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, nsarray

I have an NSArray that looks like this:

![enter image description here][1]

I need to create an NSArray that has the first URL from each of the 4 dictionaries in the array I posted.  Then I will set these as a cell's text info with `objectAtIndex:indexPath.row`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't it an array of arrays **of arrays** ?
Run a simple loop to do it :

```
NSMutableArray *urls = [NSMutableArray array];
for(NSArray *a in theArray) {
    NSArray *nestedArray = [a objectAtIndex:0];
    // if you need the whole string
    //[urls addObject:[nestedArray objectAtIndex:0]];
    // if you just need the first part of the URL
    NSArray *components = [[nestedArray objectAtIndex:0]
                           componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"];
    [urls addObject:[components objectAtIndex:0]];
}
// you got them
```

Comment: I tried this but this is what it logs out to :http://www.box.net/shared/static/5e9e0spgb26xzv2cokcu.png.  

This log has less brackets than the initial one so we got rid of one array, but I still need just an array for the first URL of each group;

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  One last thing, can you update that last code so it also takes these lines into affect? Thanks!     `NSArray *components = [urlString componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"];
    NSString *newString = [components objectAtIndex:0];`